# How to combine matrix(or list of lists) with whitespaces and letters into string?

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

How can I combine this array in one string?

```
array(['  HHHHHHH HHHHHHHHHHH       HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH    ',
       ' E       E               EEE                       ',
       '                     TT                            ',
       '                       CC                      CCCC'])
```

Result should look like this:

```
   result = 'EHHHHHHHEHHHHHHHHHHHTTCCEEEHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCCCC'
```

Comment: `some_string_with_spaces.replace(' ', '')`

Comment: Are you sure you lined up the `EEE` and `CC` correctly?

Comment: it will not be the way I wants it

Comment: @thebjorn yes,i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
array =['  HHHHHHH HHHHHHHHHHH       HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH    ',
        ' E       E               EEE                       ',
        '                     TT                            ',
        '                       CC                      CCCC']
result = []
for pos in zip(*array):                   # create tuples of chars from the same index in all strings
    char = ''.join(pos).replace(' ', '')  # remove all space chars
    if char:                              # if there's anything left (ie. skip the char at index 0)
        result.append(char[-1])           # then append the char from the array closest to the bottom
result = ''.join(result)                  # convert back to string
print result
```

which prints

```
EHHHHHHHEHHHHHHHHHHHTTCCEEEHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCCCC
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick way would be to use `zip` to process character by character and just take the max at each position;

```
arr = ['  HHHHHHH HHHHHHHHHHH       HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH    ',
       ' E       E               EEE                       ',
       '                     TT                            ',
       '                       CC                      CCCC']

''.join(max(x) for x in zip(*arr))

' EHHHHHHHEHHHHHHHHHHHTTCCEEEHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCCCC'
```

Comment: If the spaces should really be eliminated, a quick `.replace(' ', '')` will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a numpy solution:

```
>>> x
array(['  HHHHHHH HHHHHHHHHHH       HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH    ',
       ' E       E               EEE                       ',
       '                     TT                            ',
       '                       CC                      CCCC'],
      dtype='<U51')
>>> x.view('u4').reshape(len(x), -1).max(0).view(x.dtype).item(0).strip()
'EHHHHHHHEHHHHHHHHHHHTTCCEEEHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCCCC'
```

Timings:

```
f_pp  5.941 us
f_tb 27.473 us
f_ji 21.265 us
```

Code to produce timings:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

x = np.array(['  HHHHHHH HHHHHHHHHHH       HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH    ',
              ' E       E               EEE                       ',
              '                     TT                            ',
              '                       CC                      CCCC'])

def f_pp():
    return x.view('u4').reshape(len(x), -1).max(0).view(x.dtype).item(0).strip()

def f_tb():         
    result = []
    for pos in zip(*x):                       # create tuples of chars from the same index in all string
        char = ''.join(pos).replace(' ', '')  # remove all space chars
        if char:                              # if there's anything left (ie. skip the char at index 0)
            result.append(char[-1])           # then append the char from the array closest to the bottom
    return ''.join(result)                    # convert back to string

def f_ji():
    return ''.join(max(y) for y in zip(*x)).strip()

for f in (f_pp, f_tb, f_ji):
    print(f.__name__, f'{timeit(f, number=1000) * 1000:>6.3f} us')
```